# Flash Pro's should be able to solve in seconds loading a movie

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I have this action script that pulls images from a xml file

```
> myPhoto = new XML();
> myPhoto.ignoreWhite = true;
> myPhoto.onLoad = function(success) {
>   //portfolioTag = this.firstChild;
>   numimages =
> this.firstChild.childNodes.length;
>   spacing = 28;   for (i=0; i<numimages;
> i++) {        this.picHolder =
> this.firstChild.childNodes[i];
>       this.thumbHolder =
> thumbnails.createEmptyMovieClip("thumbnail"+i,
> i);       this.thumbHolder._x = i*spacing;
>       this.thumbLoader =
> this.thumbHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("thumbnail_image",
> 0);
>       this.thumbLoader.loadMovie(this.picHolder.attributes.thmb);
>       this.thumbHolder.title =
> this.picHolder.attributes.title;
>       this.thumbHolder.main =
> this.picHolder.attributes.main;
>       this.thumbHolder.onRelease =
> function() {          getURL(this.main,
> "_self");             loadMovie(this.main);
>           main_txt.text = this.main;      };  }
> }; myPhoto.load("languages.xml");
```

I want to load movies into the flash from the xml when someone clicks on one of the images. I suspect to make this possible I need to change this part of the actionscript

```
this.thumbHolder.onRelease =
> function() {          getURL(this.main,
> "_self");             loadMovie(this.main);
>           main_txt.text = this.main;      };  }
> }; myPhoto.load("languages.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to remove `getURL(...)`, since that will push you to another page. Also `loadMovie(url, target)` needs a target.

Comment: this.thumbHolder.onRelease = function() {
   loader.loadMovie(this.main ,112);
   main_txt.text = this.main;
  };
 I have tried this but with no success

Comment: loadMovieNum(this.main, 122);
   loader.loadMovie(this.main);
   main_txt.text = this.main;